# Rotation of Orthographic Camera

Tags: android, camera, libgdx

I am able to rotate camera with this code

```
camera.zoom = 3//in constructor
if(camera.zoom>1)
    {
    camera.zoom-=0.01f;
    camera.rotate(15);
    }
```

this is done in render, Now zooming effect works properly but when zooming completes my screen is stay rotated with current angle. like below.
[image]

I want that my screen stops after zooming at 0 degree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code snippet

```
**camera.zoom=3;**
```

and in each iteration  you are zooming camera by **0.01** till **camera.zoom > 1**
 so you have total 20 iteration for zooming

Then rotate with **18** degree angle after iteration it will rotate in **360** degree.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this method to calculate current angle of camera:

```
public float getCameraCurrentXYAngle(Camera cam)
{
    return (float)Math.atan2(cam.up.x, cam.up.y)*MathUtils.radiansToDegrees;
}
```

Then I call rotate method like this:

```
camera.rotate(rotationAngle - getCameraCurrentXYAngle(camera));
```

This code works, but it will rotate immediately in one call. to rotate it by a speed, you need to calculate appropriate 'rotationAngle' for every frame.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried rotating a multiple of 1.8 degrees with each iteration? Then you're image should have completed a number of full rotations once the 200 iterations have passed.

Answer (score 0):

attention, the computer can't correctly represent most real numbers!

in binary 0.01 is a periodic number, so it will be truncated/rounded.

substrating/adding float numbers a few hundred times will add the rounding error and thus give you horribly wrong results.

(e.g. after 200 substractions, your camera.zoom value will be ~ 1.0000019 - NOT 1.0!)

that's why your loop is repeated 201 times, giving you a zoom value of 0.9900019 and a rotation of 361.7996 ~ 361.8 (when using 1.8 as in alex's answer).

you could use libGDX Interpolation functions:

```
time += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(); //the rounding error is futile here,
//because it'll increase the animation time by max. 1 frame
camera.zoom = Interpolation.linear.apply(3, 1, Math.min(time, 1));
camera.rotate = Interpolation.linear.apply(0, 360, Math.min(time, 1));
```

this code would create an one second long animation of zooming from 3 to 1 and rotating from 0 to 360 (simply one whole roation)